# Overstaying ESTA Visa waiver in the US

Tags: visas, usa, esta, overstaying

I recently discovered that I will be over-staying my 90 day visa waiver by 2 days.
My question is about leaving the country as I fly from NYC to LA before flying home to Australia and I'm wondering that if because the Visa has technically expired will I be allowed to fly from one US state to another or will I be forced to fly directly out of the US from NYC?

Comment: And how did it turn out? Were you allowed to leave the country without any problems?

Answer (score 10):

There is no requirement for visa to be valid for travelling within the US as long as your [identification](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids) is valid you will be allowed to board the flight.  The problem will come if you decide after flying back to Australia to re-enter the US.  More likely then not you will not be able to enter under a VWP, since you have overstayed your visa.  Whether or not it results in all out entry ban remains to be seen.

Comment: You only get banned if you overstayed more than 180 days. You "only" lose your VWP privileges.

Answer (score 8):

[From a lawyer](http://www.jsimmslaw.com/blog/2013/8/7/overstayed-the-visa-waiver-programesta-can-i-return-to-the-us):

> Overstaying the Visa Waiver Program means that you will face more
>   difficulty trying to return to the US.  You will be ineligible for the
>   Visa Waiver Program in the future, because you overstayed.  You will
>   have to apply for a B-2 visitor visa to visit the US.
>
> If you overstay the time that you were given on the visa waiver
>   program you will start accruing unlawful presence.  You may be barred
>   from returning to the US for 3 or 10 years depending on your length of
>   overstay.

So long story short, you'll be breaking US law by overstaying. And that's NEVER a good position to be in.  Sure, you'll likely to be able to fly to LA, as they're just looking for ID (eg passport) - you don't go through immigration.  But when you exit the country (LA), they're going to be asking questions, and you may find yourself with a flag on your passport, or worse.

Remember, even if you're not ever intending to return to the US, having this on your record may impact your ability to travel / immigrate to other countries in the future as well.  Even if you think you won't need it, never say never, and if at all possible, fly earlier, or call the [CBP](http://cbp.gov/) or your consulate and ask for the best possible course of action.

Comment: ... except there's no immigration on the way out of the US. They'll probably still know because airlines supply manifests to the authorities, but I don't think you'll have issues leaving the country. Re-entry will be a different matter.

Comment: @Sam I'm having a weird memory blank - there's really no passport control when you leave the US? Isn't that where you need to hand over your I-94 (if you have one)?  The other concern is whether or not you'd get flagged when you checkin for your flight, I guess.

Comment: Now you're making me doubt myself! But I'm pretty sure there isn't, because it was one of the odd things I noticed. There's the guy checking passports when entering security, but I think that's just to ensure names match up.

Comment: The I-94 is no longer in use. I am sure the passport is scanned just before security and that should probably go into a database

Comment: What if I walk into Canada?  I recall talking to someone who left Australia by freighter, and Australia had no record of her ever leaving.  That caused some issues next time she wanted to get in, but I don't recall the details.

Comment: @gerrit I was thinking about this earlier, as I did this near White Rock (near Vancouver).  I'm fairly sure we just walked around the US side, no checks, and lined up at the Canadian side...

Comment: The question boils down to the burden of proof.  Must I be able to provide proof that I had left, or must US immigration proof that I had not?

Comment: @MarkMayo: There is absolutely no exit checks in the U.S., either at airports, or at land crossings. In theory it is possible for CBP to perform random checks at the gate, however, I have never seen this happen.

Comment: @gerrit: You need to prove that you have left. But U.S. will have records of it, if you did everything correctly. If you received a paper I-94 (if you arrived in the U.S. prior to May 2013), you need to turn it in when you leave. If you arrived after they automated the I-94, you do not need to do anything when you leave.

Comment: If there are no exit checks and I didn't need to do anything, how do they know when I left?  Flights are not the only method of transportation...

Comment: @gerrit I've always wondered that too, but I suspect Canada's CBP equivalent shares information with the US, so that border's covered for land transport. The US CBP would get manifests from providers of other non-land modes of transport to elsewhere too. Mexico is more interesting - when I crossed over, the Mexicans just waved people through, without even checking passports!

Comment: Also, just found this - "Generally the U.S. does not have mandatory exit controls. However the Bureau of Customs and Border Protection is currently testing US-VISIT exit procedures at 12 major airports and 3 seaports. If you leave from one of these ports, you are required to confirm your departure...The exit confirmation will be added to your travel records to demonstrate compliance with the terms of your admission. Ultimately, most foreign visitors will be required to check out before leaving the United States." http://canberra.usembassy.gov/visa_waiver_prog.html

Comment: @jogabonito no, the passport check before security is an ID check only, done by TSA, not CBP.  They are only interested in making certain that you are you and that your boarding pass was issued to you.  I've routinely used a foreign passport with no visa or even entry stamp at that check for the last couple of years, and nobody even blinked an eye.  Next time I'm going on an international flight, I plan to show my driver's license there.

Answer (score 2):

Overstaying your visa duration is definitely a frowned upon offence and can damage your chances of being allowed reentry into the United States. Whilst doing the visa wizard on the immigration visa website one of the questions is: "Have you ever overstayed a visa, even by one day?"

The United States takes such violations VERY seriously, so I would tread carefully. I think your situation can't really be answered on this site, I recommend speaking with an immigration lawyer who can assist with obtaining the right information and what your options are.